# Why do lambda functions need to capture [this] pointer explicitly in c++20?

Tags: c++, lambda, this, c++20, capture

Pre-c++20, the `this` pointer is captured in [=] implicity. So what's the reason that c++20 decided that user should write [=, this] to capture this pointer explicitly, I mean, without this change, the pre-c++20 code could have any code-smell or potential bug?

Any good sample or reason for this language change?

Comment: I think you'll find the motivation in [p0409r2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0409r2.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is explain in [P0806](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0806r2.html), which as the title says, "Deprecate[d] implicit capture of `this` via `[=]`"

The argument in the paper is that at this point we had `[this]` (captures the `this` pointer) and `[*this]` (captures the object itself), and `[&]` (captures the object by reference, which is basically capturing the `this` pointer by value). So it could be ambiguous whether `[=]` should mean `[this]` or `[*this]` and potentially surprising that it means the former (since `[=]` functions as a reference capture in this context).

Thus, you have to write `[=, this]` or `[=, *this]`, depending on which one of the two you actually intended.

---

As an aside, it's worth nothing that the paper claims:

> The change does not break otherwise valid C++20 code

Yet if you compile with warnings enabled and `-Werror`, as many people do (and should unless you have a compelling reason not to - which there are), this change of course broke lots of otherwise valid C++20 code.

Comment: "*this change of course broke lots of otherwise valid C++20 code.*" That's true of deprecating *anything*.